# How can I tell if someone copied files off of my Internal HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, applescript, catalina, security, console

I sent my laptop to replace my old HDD with a new SSD and  the person doing the repair kept the HDD with him for many months after putting the SSD in. Is there a way to find out if my files have been copied in any way or was the drive cloned? I have opened the HDD and checked what was in there, but there are still some sub folders that I didn't touch so considering that is there anything that I can do that will show logs of where my HDD was plugged in? or was any file or folder accessed. Some kind of Github software would be good. And it's been quite a few months since this event and also the HDD was in AFPS format and the HDD is the exact same which was working as internal storage in my macbook pro no changes in that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell if your drive was accessed *reliably*. There may be indications that the drive *was* accessed, but the absence of these indicators does not mean that the drive was *not* accessed.

If a drive is mounted read-only or simply cloned, no information gets written back to the disk. Thus, you won't be able to find any differences (apart from SMART information, but you would need to know the exact characteristics before the drive was given to someone else).

Additionally, since you apparently already accessed the drive in read-write mode, you cannot tell whether timestamps etc. were modified by the other person: it might have been your system (without you realizing it). So unless you find new data of which you can tell with 100% certainty that it was not coming from your system, you're not going to be able to tell whether the other person has accessed your drive.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response! I have only clicked on the main partition and some files in it not every so by any chance is it possible to use them to know if anything was taken?